# How variable contain in memory address

Tags: c++

I know that pointer has address of first memory byte
If code is

```
int a=10;
int *p = &a;
```

"a" has 4byte memory and value of p will be "0x61feb8"

so "a" has address of "0x61feb9 , 0x61feba, 0x61febb"

1. Is it right?
2. Can we call value of "a" with *"0x61feb9"?  not for calling detail(maybe use pointer)
   I mean *0x61feb9 == *0x61feb8?

Comment: You may want to check out [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which, subjectively speaking, if you're not interfacing with a binary format, is mostly a implementation detail.

Comment: Trying to dereference a misaligned pointer invokes undefined behavior, so you shouldn’t do it.  The only address that is usable for an int-pointer is the lowest one in the int.

Comment: No.  `0x61feb9` is a literal of type `unsigned`.   That is not a pointer so cannot be dereferenced (i.e.  `*(0x61feb9)` is not a valid expression).     Use `*p = 42` if (for example) you want to assign the value of `a` - that is valid since `p` is a pointer (the type matters as well as the value).    Also, an `int` is not guaranteed to be represented using four bytes.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it right?

Yeah.

> 2. Can we call value of "a" with *"0x61feb9"? not for calling detail(maybe use pointer) I mean *0x61feb9 == *0x61feb8?

No. The language definition requires you to dereference `0x61feb8`, not `0x61feb9`.